# Synchronize Anthy Preferences

Tags: input, ime, japanese

I use the Anthy IME with ibus for japanese language input on US standard keyboards. I've made certain customizations in the preferences that I'd like to replicate across my other machines, all running Ubuntu 14.04. I'm comfortable using ansible for the synchronization, but I can't seem to find precisely where the preferences are stored.

`~/.anthy` seemed logical, but I'm not convinced after an inspection of its contents.

Does anyone know what I copy to sync my anthy preferences?

Answer (score -1):

I have tried the same thing, ibus-anthy keeps the configuration into many different places. other than ~./anthy
For example:

- the key assignment is stored `/usr/share/ibus-anthy/setup/anthyprefs.py`
- the user dictionary is stored `~./anthy/private_words_default`

And I am not sure where other settings are stored or is it capable to run appropriately if I copy them into a different machine esp. different keyboard layout or different version of ibus and anthy, I think it could go wrong.

So I gave ibus-anthy up and install **fcitx-mozc** instead, it has an export feature for key assignment and dictionary. It's safe and compatible with another Mozc setting, I keep them in a cloud server my exported key assign file and dictionary.

Mozc is actually wiser than Anthy, it remembers the word I often choose and suggest several words before I finish typing, I need to type first 2 letters or 3 and Mozc shows whole words (selectable with tab key).
Only the thing, Mozc doesn't work appropriately with iBus input method after 16.04, I need to switch ibus into fcitx.

Best Regards,